# Data streaming in Apache superset from BQ?

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-superset, pybigquery, spring-cloud-gcp-bigquery

I am new to superset and wanted to know if there's any way to perform data streaming in big query using apache superset? Currently, I have set up the database in apache superset with big query but when I update the table data using SQL commands in bigquery it doesn't reflect in superset. Is there any way to get the streaming of data to superset?

Answer (score 0):

I've looked around the Apache Superset [documentation](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/) and couldn't find anything related to "streaming data" from a source, what I think in this scenario is happening, is that you have a dashboard which use the data from the table you have in BigQuery, and after adding some new information to the table you expect that change to be reflected in the dashboard automatically.

Based on this my theory is that Superset saves the result of your query on memory or it could be using BigQuery [cached results](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results#python) which may not allow the dashboard to automatically update the data and see the changes made. My suggestion is to either [run](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/admintutorial.html#exploring-your-data) again the query for your table to try to get the latest data. On the other hand, if Superset use cached results, you'll have to take a look at the configuration used for Superset for BigQuery looking for a way to disable it.